# Is %a an option of stat?

Tags: files, stat

```
Usage: stat [OPTION]... FILE...
Display file or file system status.

  -L, --dereference     follow links
  -f, --file-system     display file system status instead of file status
  -c  --format=FORMAT   use the specified FORMAT instead of the default;
                          output a newline after each use of FORMAT
      --printf=FORMAT   like --format, but interpret backslash escapes,
                          and do not output a mandatory trailing newline.
                          If you want a newline, include \n in FORMAT
  -t, --terse           print the information in terse form
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

The valid format sequences for files (without --file-system):

  %a   Access rights in octal
  %A   Access rights in human readable form

...
```

Is `%a` also an option?

How can we use it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a *format specifier* for the *option* `-c` rather than an option in itself e.g.

```
$ stat -c '%a' myfile
664
```

or

```
$ stat -c '%n %a' myfile
myfile 664
```

Comment: Thanks. without any format specifier, what is the default format for `-c`? Does the default output all the information about a file?

Comment: At least for the GNU `coreutils` version, AFAIK there is no default format for `-c`, and omitting the format argument is an error. OTOH the default behavior when __no__ option is given (i.e. just `stat myfile`) __is__ to print all information. Other implementations may be different.

Comment: @Tim, the source code for `stat` from coreutils v8.23, should clarify this. See [main](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/stat.c?id=v8.23#n1569) and the [default_format](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/stat.c?id=v8.23#n1315) function. It's basically something like `"  File: %N\n\  Size: %-10s\tBlocks: %-10b IO Block: %-6o %F\n..."`.